# jQuery template not showing data elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I'm trying to get the jQuery template feature working but have finally come to a dead end. From all my investigation the code listing below should work and I expect to get:

- file1.txt, 123456, 2012-01-01
- file2.txt, 234567, 2012-01-02
- file3.txt, 345678, 2012-01-03

but instead I get

- , ,
- , ,
- , ,

Clearly the library is loading and the code is running but for some reason it will not pick up the data elements. The code behaves the same regardless of the browser. I've tried compiling the template and not, each with the same results.

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but I've been pulling my hair out for about 8 hours staring at examples (and I've not that much hair left!). Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery Template Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="inc/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var exampleData = [
            { name: "file1.txt", size: "123456", date: "2012-01-01" },
            { name: "file2.txt", size: "234567", date: "2012-01-02" },
            { name: "file3.txt", size: "345678", date: "2012-01-03" }
        ];

        var markup = "<li>${name}, ${size}, ${date}</li>";
        $.template( "exampleTemplate", markup );

        $.tmpl("exampleTemplate", exampleData).appendTo("#target");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="target"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any javascript console errors?

Comment: Nope - that's the hair pulling part! I've got no real feedback on the problem to try to track it down...

Comment: I just ran it locally using Microsoft's cdn http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js and it worked.

Comment: Ok, it _was_ a simple, dumb mistake on my part.

I'm using this code on a JSP page (as part of a larger servlet/jsp application). The server is mucking up the javascript by removing the ${name}, ${size}, and ${date} references, hence the resulting empty template I was seeing. Once I changed the page extension to .html it worked just fine.

Now I don't know if this can be remedied so the templates can be used on a JSP, hand-in-hand with any other processing that needs to happen, but that is a separate question.

Thanks to Jack for the prodding, it was just what I needed! :-)

Comment: As a follow up, yes the templates can be properly inserted into the response for a JSP, you just have to escape the special characters like so: var markup="<li>\$\{name\}</li>. Thanks again!

Comment: i had the same problem,this help me thanks lot (using escaping character).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with JSP: Use \$ to escape EL expression